# How about 'to spend time worried?'

Tags: grammar, usage

I have seen and heard many times 'to spend time -ing~.'
But I have encountered a few times 'to spend time worried~.'
Is that grammatically correct?
If so, can I understand that as 'to spend time (being) worried~?'

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct - *worried* can be an adjective.

As an analogy, *painted* is the past tense of *paint*, but can also be an adjective for something that you have painted:

> He saw a freshly painted house.

But the construction of worried is a little different - it doesn't have to do with the verb worry - it is formed from the *noun* worry.  It is somewhat rare, but many nouns can form adjectives in this way - *bespectacled* (wearing spectacles - eyeglasses)*, freckled, double-jointed, bearded*, etc.  The word *troubled* is very much like *worried*.